# Some JS files can not be debugged in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a ReactJS app. Everything is OK except this issue:
Some (very few) files are can not be debugged. This is visualized using two UI options in Chrome DevTools:

- dirs containing these files are greyed out in the Filesystem folder structure
- when opening this file in devtools it doesn't have a green light in the tab
  [image]